# Jekyll grabbing files from folder with same initial letters

Tags: jekyll

This problem is a bit hard to describe.

I'm trying to capture a path to an image folder that's titled like the current `page.title`, but slugified. In other words, if the current page title is "Kevin N", the image folder is named "kevinn", and the `page.title | slugify` filter outputs this in the code below.

```
<div class="model-gallery">
{% capture gallery_path %}pics/models/gallery/{{ page.title | slugify | replace: '-','' | replace: 'å','a' | replace: 'ä','a' | replace: 'ö','o' }}{% endcapture %}
{% for image in site.static_files %}
    {% if image.path contains gallery_path %}
        {{image.size}}
        <img class="gallery-item" src="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ image.path }}" alt="{{page.title}}, {{site.title}}" />
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

In the case of the page being titled "Kevin N", the `capture` statement above would output `pics/models/gallery/kevinn`.

This has worked before, but I just added a new .md file for a new page titled "Ken". There exists an older page titled "Kenneth". They both begin with "Ken" in  the title. This seems to create problems with the loop above, as the `capture` is both grabbing the file path for "Ken" and "Kenneth", adding the images connected to "Kenneth" after the images connected to "Ken".

The problem is only occuring on the page titled "Ken". If I visit the "Kenneth" page, it's only showing the "Kenneth" images, like it should. So there seems to be some kind of behaviour where the `capture` code is grabbing entities with the same letters in the beginning.

Any suggestions for solving this?

**Edit:**
I'm suspecting that this line is causing the problem:
`{% if image.path contains gallery_path %}`, as it's true that the path `pics/models/gallery/kenneth` contains `pics/models/gallery/ken`. Is there any way to be more exact in this comparison?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the `gallery_path` being written without a trailing slash. So when `{% if image.path contains gallery_path %}` is trying to see if the gallery path is present in the image path, that check becomes true since `pics/models/gallery/kenneth` contains `pics/models/gallery/ken`.

The very easy fix is to just add a trailing slash to the `gallery_path` after the filters, like this:

```
{% capture gallery_path %}pics/models/gallery/{{ page.title | slugify | replace: '-','' | replace: 'å','a' | replace: 'ä','a' | replace: 'ö','o' }}/{% endcapture %}
```

With this, `pics/models/gallery/kenneth` no longer contains `pics/models/gallery/ken/`, since the trailing slash is making the path exact.